# How can I update my database table with the result of my query

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable, mysql-5.6

I am a French designer and I have a SQL problem. My MySQL server is in v5.6 and i ask for help because I have a syntax problem. I think you can bring me a solution.

I have a data base called "scores":

| id | pseudo | tempsstage1mili | rangstage1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pseudo1 | 20100 | --- |
| 2 | pseudo2 | 16900 | --- |

and I ask this to MySQL :

```
SELECT pseudo,
 @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM scores p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  tempsstage1mili;
```

With this command, MySQL return this :

| pseudo | rank |
| --- | --- |
| pseudo2 | 1 |
| pseudo1 | 2 |

At this step it's perfect but now, I want to Update my table called "scores" with the result. The column I have to Update is called "rangstage1" with the column "rank"

I want to get that :

| id | pseudo | tempsstage1mili | rangstage1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pseudo1 | 20100 | 2 |
| 2 | pseudo2 | 16900 | 1 |

Could you help me ? Please ? You are hope !

Thank you !

Comment: Thank your for your help, i add this in the question.

Comment: Not realy, the query return : pseudo 2 | (rank) 1 /// pseudo 1 | (rank) 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn this into an `update`:

```
SET @curRank = 0;

UPDATE scores
    SET rankstage1 = (@curRank := @curRank + 1)
    ORDER BY tempsstage1mili;
```

Comment: Yes ! This solution works very well ! Thanks for paying attention to my problem. You are a great help on my project.

Comment: Hello Gordon. I would now like to convert your solution to insert it in a PHP file. I admit I'm not good enough to do it alone. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

After some tries I think this will help:

```
UPDATE scores s
INNER JOIN 
( select i.pseudo, i.rank from (SELECT pseudo,
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM scores p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  tempsstage1mili ) i ) a
ON s.pseudo = a.pseudo
SET s.rangstage1 = a.rank ;
```

Please try and give me feedback, is it working ?

Comment: Good afternoon basha04, thanks for paying attention to my problem. Your solution is working but the next solution, by Gordon Linoff, is shorter. I will use this one. Thank you again.

Comment: Hello basha04. I just inserted your solution in a PHP file which controls the database and it works perfectly. Thank you again.